# easy way to change php array to individual variables

Tags: php

The following array is a print_r of an array called $result.
I would like to know the best way to change the array to a set of variables that I can accesss any of these items as a variable for example if I want to see [queued_at] value I can just use a variable called $queued_at.

Array ( [response] => Array ( [success] => 1 [result] => Array ( [success] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 16623749 [device_id] => 22233 [message] => hi gg 2 [status] => pending [send_at] => 1463693469 [queued_at] => 0 [sent_at] => 0 [delivered_at] => 0 [expires_at] => 1463697069 [canceled_at] => 0 [failed_at] => 0 [received_at] => 0 [error] => [created_at] => 1463693469 [contact] => Array ( [id] => 3801452 [name] => Gg [number] => +64210419805 ) ) ) [fails] => Array ( ) ) ) [status] => 200 )

Here is a formatted version of array:

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [success] => 1
            [result] => Array
                (
                    [success] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 16627521
                                    [device_id] => 22269
                                    [message] => test 10:37
                                    [status] => pending
                                    [send_at] => 1463700123
                                    [queued_at] => 0
                                    [sent_at] => 0
                                    [delivered_at] => 0
                                    [expires_at] => 1463703723
                                    [canceled_at] => 0
                                    [failed_at] => 0
                                    [received_at] => 0
                                    [error] => 
                                    [created_at] => 1463700123
                                    [contact] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 3801855
                                            [name] => +64212465478
                                            [number] => +64212465478
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                    [fails] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => 200
)
```

Comment: Please format your array.  This is difficult to read.

Comment: Of course, the real question is "why?"

Comment: here is a formatted version of array:

Answer (score 4):

You can use extract() to do that, eg. extract($array, EXTR_OVERWRITE), but you need to note a couple of things:

1. If there are two items with the same key - one has to be overwritten or skipped. That's a limitation of your own task.
2. I see that you have nested arrays, extract() may be not smart enough to work those, but you can try a nested_extract() method proposed here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php (see the comments section)
3. I wouldn't recommend doing it anyway. If you just need an easy way to access data inside of your array - just write a smart finder function that looks for a specific key in nested arrays.

Alternative solution for you - instead of creating extra, temporary variables, simply access data inside your array based on key name:

```
// This function will convert multi-dimensional array to a single dimensional one
// If two items have the same keys - the former will be overwritten
function flatten(array $array)
{
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($a, $key) use (&$return) { $return[$key] = $a; });
    return $return;
}

// This is a wrapper for the whole feature - flatten array and look for a key
function nested_key_search(array $array, $key)
{
    $flat = flatten($array);
    return $flat[$key] ?: false;
}

print_r(nested_key_search($array, 'coffee'));
```

Comment: I know this is probably a simple question - so apologies in advance. What is the best way to just simply get the value for [device_id] in the array - I am just a bit confused due to the nesting levels.

Comment: `$array['response']['result']['success'][0]['device_id']`

Comment: @dkmarsh sure, see the new second part of the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `extract` function. This will dump all your array keys into the current variable pool. There are several flags available to determine what to do in the case of collisions. For example:

```
extract($result, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "r_");
```

will give you access to all of your array keys as variables prefixed with "r_".

Comment: thanks d amos - can I please clarify this so if I wanted to get device_id would I do the following ?
 extract($result, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "r_");
 
 echo $r_device_id;

Comment: No, that wouldn't work actually. The key is too deep in the array. I think most of us misunderstood your original question, or at least didn't realize what it was exactly you had in mind. The second part of @Denis Mysenko is potentially a better answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think that by using **variable variable** within ordinary `foreach` loop will give You what You want.

Example :

```
$array = $result['response']['result']['success'][0];

foreach($array as $varname => $value)
{
  if(is_string($value)) $$varname = $value;
}
```